# Как перечислять ключевые слова?

Tags: javascript

Как нужно перечислять слова в `indexOf`? Как правильно? Пробую так:

```
indexOf('КлючевоеСлово1','КлючевоеСлово2');
```

и

```
indexOf('КлючевоеСлово1' || 'КлючевоеСлово2');
```

но не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.indexOf` первым аргументом принимает подстроку, которую требуется найти, а вторым - число, означающее с какого символа строки искать подстроку.

Как Вы хотите сделать - не получится. Придётся писать свою функцию, которая будет в цикле искать вхождение одной из подстрок:

```
String.prototype.indexOf_array = function(array) {
    var str = this;
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var index = str.indexOf(array[i]);
        if(index !== -1) return index;
    }

    return -1;
};

"asdf".indexOf_array(['ab', 'aa']) //-1
"asdf".indexOf_array(['ab', 'sd']) //1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если почитать [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) метода `indexOf`, можно узнать, что он принимает только одну строку для поиска. Второй параметр необязателен и представляет собой индекс начала поиска. Если вы хотите найти одно из нескольких слов, вам придётся вызвать `indexOf` насколько раз:

```
var str = 'abcdefxyz'
if (str.indexOf('abc') !== -1 || str.indexOf('def') !== -1) {
    // найдено совпадение
}
```

Если слов больше 2-3, целесообразно будет сложить их в массив и искать их в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
'КлючевоеСлово1'.indexOf('Слово')
```

Можно еще указать позицию исходной строки, с которой начинать поиск:

```
'КлючевоеСлово1'.indexOf('Слово', 5)
```